# How to optimize table size by deleting columns or just emptying them

Tags: mysql, optimization

Should I set a column to NULL Or DELETE it to reduce DB Size. 
For example in the below image you can see "SmallImageURL" (number 13) should I set it to NULL or delete the column.

( If I delete the column, Application will start throwing errors, Is it worth to delete the column and fix the errors instead of emptying it ?, My concern is only about Reducing DB size and optimizing performance)

[image]
[image]

Comment: The table has millions of records, I set NULL to many columns to reduce DB size. Is it worth to delete them ? Thats all I want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  I doubt if it is worth doing either.

Medium answer:  It depends on a lot of things.  You could calculate `SUM(LENGTH(col1)) + SUM(LENGTH(COL2)) + ...` to get a crude estimate.  But (as the long answer explains) that savings may be an over- *or* under-estimate in the case of `NULLing`.  In the case of `DROPping`, it is likely to be an underestimate of the shrinkage.

Long answer:

(It would help if you had provided `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

In MySQL, `VARCHAR(512)` will take a little bit of space even if empty or `NULL`.  At most it will take 2050 bytes since it is utf8mb4, but it is unlikely to really be that big.

Since you have a number of large `VARCHAR` columns, they *may* be placed in an off-row storage that is handled in a different way.  This depends on how bulky all the columns are and what the `ROW_FORMAT` is.  I am assuming you are using InnoDB; MyISAM works quite differently.

Because of the way setting a column to `NULL` works, you may not save as much space as you would calculate.

`DROP COLUMN` is a drastic approach.  It will take a long time because it will copy the table over *and* rebuild all the indexes.  But, in doing so, it will defragment both the data and the indexes, squeezing out more space than simply NULLing would do.  The `DROP` approach *might* reduce the table size more than you would compute.

But... If you have `innodb_file_per_table = 0`, no space will be returned to the OS by *either* method!  It might even *increase* the space used!  This is because a copy of the table is needed during the `DROP`.

With `innodb_file_per_table = 1`, you will recoup the freed space, but only *after* needing space for a copy of the table.

Why do you want to shrink the table?  My above answers assume you are getting low on disk space.

Note `DROP` does the same as `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, with the additional feature of removing the column.

If you are hoping to speed things up by shrinking the table, forget it.

Answer (score 0):

You will pack more records into one block and likely achieve better performance by removing unused columns. This will be less impactful for VARCHAR columns which dynamically allocate space and won't actually be using much if null.

Answer (score 0):

When looking to reduce the size of a database, you need to ask a few questions:

1. First - should you just add disk space? Databases do tend to grow over time; at some point, you need to provide more disk space, or archive old data.
2. Do you have old data that's no longer used? Look at archiving this data. Generally, this will involve: saving a full backup of the database as it exists today, so you can stand it up if you have to access the old data; or, copying the old data out to a different database (again, so you have it if you have an unusual need). The "old data" will normally span multiple tables, so you need to carefully coordinate what you're doing.
3. What's taking up the most space? You may find that there's something unexpected consuming a lot of space.
4. Are there indexes that can be safely removed without causing performance issues? Removing an index generally loses no data, though it can cause major performance issues.
5. Do you have fragmented indexes (or tables)? Defragmenting them may release some space.
6. Review your database design - do you have tables that are no longer in use? If so, you can look at removing or emptying those tables. It's safest to empty the table, rather than dropping it; this will be unlikely to cause problems with your code.
7. If you're still having disk space issues - should you just add disk space? I know, we already asked. but, if you haven't found a solution with the above steps, disk space may be the only good answer.
8. As a last resort: Are there columns in existing tables that are no longer in use? Are the data types such that setting the contents to NULL or an empty string will reduce the space consumed? Can you safely drop the column? Again, either deleting or dropping the column can cause issues with your code (especially dropping the column).

I'm not a MySQL expert, so there may be things that can be done that are specific to MySQL.

In SQL Server (the system I work in), another thing to check would be:

- Are there tables without a clustered index? Deleting rows from these tables doesn't necessarily release the space those rows took up. I have been able to free up space in a table by simply adding a clustered index (or converting an existing index to a clustered index).

Also - be very careful when removing data from your system. If you remove data that you need, putting it back can be very difficult and time-consuming.  Again, the first thing to look at when you're short on disk space is seeing if you can add some more disk space....